# python script for Reverse Flow

Tags: python

learning to code here

```py
for i in range(0,5):
    for j in range(0,i+1):
        print("*",end='\t')
    
    print("")
```

will get you

```
*
*       *
*       *       *
*       *       *       *
*       *       *       *       *
```

but I want it in reverse

```
* * * * * 
* * * *
* * *
* * 
*
```

how do I get that done?

Comment: Loops can count down as well as up. Surely the book/tutorial that you are following has such examples.

Comment: In addition to the option of making the outer loop count down instead of up, you could also make the inner loop count up to `5-i` instead of to `i+1`.

Answer (score 1):

A pythonic way to accomplish this would be by using list comprehension and library functions.

```
star_list = ["\t".join(["*" for i in range(j)]) for j in range(5)]
forwards_str = "\n".join(star_str)
backwards_str = "\n".join(reversed(star_str))

print(forwards_str)
print(backwards_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

oop count up to 5-i instead of to i+1

worked perfectly